# Foundation and Internet Explorer error

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, zurb-foundation

I hope someone can help me. I'm working in the design of a site for real estate. I'm working with foundation 5, it works good in chrome and firefox for mac but when I test the site in firefox and Internet Explorer 11 in a PC it looks weird. I haven't test it in olders versions of those browsers in PC yet.

I have the site in https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78083017/casinoPlaza/plantas.html

The problem is in the tab panel with the floorplan.

I'm working in the left side menu. I really don't know how to solve the problem because I don`t know where the problem is. I hope someone can help me figure out the problem and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

so the problem might be is that you used a MAC computer and usually the OS is different then Windows (PC) 
so in other words i'll put a example 
let us say if windows 8 works awesome with a touchscreen alright?
but you expect seeing the same interaction with a non-touchscreen monitor?
see? there is going to be a difference trying to adapt to the new hardware/software in your case, you might see that in MAC it looks flawless and that might be true for the mac users who visit your website but you have to know you have to calibrate the website to fit in other "formats" i would recommend you "building" your website in a PC so issues don't pop up that much as they are happening right now/

Comment: Thanks Ulises, I understand your point and thanks for your recommendations.